# Eclipse PDE build with source code

Tags: eclipse, build, pde

I have a Eclipse PDE build that creates a product.  So far so good, I can create and run my product with the Headless PDE installer.

I want to further use my build product as a "Target-Platform" to develop add-ons on it.  However, the problem I have is that this build does not contain the source code internally.

My question is, how can I setup my PDE build to also include the source code? (this would be an optional operation, as I would like to enable this only when creating a "source" version for internal development)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to include the scr folder in your plugin build file. For example, you have a plugin, and you are going to use the PDE tool to build site, and this plugin is one of the plugins to be built; then, make sure to include the src folder in this plugin build file.